# Why does the compiler for translate to assembly the use of indirect jump instructions?

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, reverse-engineering, disassembly

why compilers use of indirect jump instructions for translate code to assembly `x86` ?
example :

```
.
jmp eax
```

or

```
jmp [eax*4+ebx]
```

and which compiler(s) use from indirect jumps ?
and How can we achieve the ultimate goal of an indirect jump ?

please explain with an example.
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it's just me being tired, but I find your question a bit difficult to understand. Could you provide a more concrete example and/or explain _why_ this matters to you?

Comment: for drawing CFG graphs in assembly code generated by the compiler .

Comment: Why do you feel the need to use an indirect jump.  What do you think an indirect jump is going to give you that other forms are not?  You are likely going to need to do this in assembly by hand.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a large switch-statement like:

> switch(expr)
>   {
>           case 0: {do something; break;}
>           case 1: {break;}
>           case 2: {do something else;}
>           case 3: {do things; break;}
>           default: {do things for most cases; break;}
>           case 255: {and now for something completely different;}
>   }

the compiler might implement it using an indirect jump. However, if the switch-statement is simple enough, or not well-suited for a jump table, the compiler may instead use multiple branches.